# Showing line number with filename in ack

Tags: ack

when I search using `ack` I get results like this

```
/path/to/file/name
42: <code>goes here</code>
```

How do I get ack to return results like this instead:

```
/path/to/file/name:42 : <code>goes here</code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--nogroup` option.

If you still want blank lines between each file's results, use the `--break` option.